# How to apply django/jinja2 template filters 'escape' and 'linebreaks' correctly?

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, jinja2

I'm currently trying to escape a variable using django templating filters as below.
I use a jinja2 template engine instead of just django's primary templateing engine

```
{{ my_variable|escape|linebreaks }}
```

the output of a string with newlines is as follows:

```
Lorem ipsum <br /> dolor sit amet <br />rg srg
gs rgsr rsg serg<br />r srg
```

Ideally the

```
<br />
```

is not supposed to be escaped, as it is added by the "linebreaks" filter. There are no html tags with the original string.

I've tried:

```
{{ my_variable|linebreaks|escape }}
```

But, it turns out even worse:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum <br /> dolor sit amet <br />rg srg</p>
<p>gs rgsr rsg serg<br />r srg</p>
```

Does anyone knows whether I did something wrong with applying the template filter, and/or able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silly me, it seems that I can use:

```
{{ my_variable|forceescape|linebreaks }}
```

to force the 'escape' filter to apply first.
By default 'escape' only apply at end of all other filters despite of position, so force_escape is the other most simple alternative.

Comment: I ended up having to do `{{ my_variable|escape|linebreaks|safe }}` (as @Reiner suggested)

Just doing `forceescape` double escaped things for me.

Answer (score 5):

So you are using django's `linebreaks` filter in a jinja2 template? In that case, I would assume that the way django marks a string safe may not be compatible with jinja2, therefore escaping the tags added by django (if autoescape is active).

What if you added the safe filter from jinja2 to the end?

```
{{ my_variable|escape|linebreaks|safe }}
```

Otherwise, there is an example for a custom filter in jinja2 documentation that seems to be similar to django's linebreaks.
http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters

```
import re
from jinja2 import evalcontextfilter, Markup, escape

_paragraph_re = re.compile(r'(?:\r\n|\r|\n){2,}')

@evalcontextfilter
def nl2br(eval_ctx, value):
    result = u'\n\n'.join(u'<p>%s</p>' % p.replace('\n', '<br>\n')
                      for p in _paragraph_re.split(escape(value)))
    if eval_ctx.autoescape:
        result = Markup(result)
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the jinja2 custom filter. Though it is a more complex solution, it helped me figure out a related problem of implementing a custom filter to do target="_blank" for urlize links. Thanks!

Comment: @VKen would you mind sharing the target="_blank" urlize code? i've been looking for a way to implement that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I was using Django built-in template engine, which has the [linebreaksbr](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) (and [linesbreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatefilter-linebreaks) too). So I defined a custom filter using the same function:

```py
from django.template.defaultfilters import linebreaksbr, linebreaks

env = Environment(
    # Your config...
)
env.filters["linebreaks"] = linebreaks
env.filters["linebreaksbr"] = linebreaksbr
```